# git gc on bare repository does not clean up

Tags: git, version-control

I have a 2GB Git bare repo with 30000 commits. Unfortunally I have early added some large files over the years, which I now have cleaned up using `git filter-branch` - see e.g. [this link](http://www.ducea.com/2012/02/07/howto-completely-remove-a-file-from-git-history/). 
Identification of the culpits - see e.g. [this link](https://github.com/18F/C2/issues/439)
I have also cleaned away many old "test try" branches using `git branch -D BRANCH-NAME`. Now the fun starts :-)

In my bare repo it seems that `git gc --aggressive --prune=yes` does not reduce the directory size of the bare repo, but if I clone the bare repo and run `git gc --agressive --prune=yes` then my directory size drops to 50 MB (which is REALLY nice).

I have also tried [this nice idea](https://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/git-script-to-show-largest-pack-objects-and-trim-your-waist-line/), but it does not show SHAs or any other lead on where to cut the knife.

I could really use your input on safely getting rid of my bare repo storage in a systematic way.

Further relevant links that I read, tried, but it did not help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532740/do-i-ever-need-to-run-git-gc-on-a-bare-repo), [this](https://github.com/18F/C2/issues/439), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312439/git-gc-aggressive-prune-all-does-not-remove-big-file-from-repository)

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/28720432/6309? (gc+repack+prune)

Comment: Did you removed the refs/original folder that a filter-branch might have left? (if you did it on the bare repo)

Comment: @VonC thanx - refs/original is clean

Comment: @VonC I tried gc+repack+prune (thanx), but no dice. I still have a HUGE file objects/pack/pack-a3bd6008bef2cd518bb95496cb8435ed65b9ddcd.pack

Comment: @axiac tried - did not help though. Thanx anyway

Comment: I also tried  git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=all --all
no dice

Comment: Can you try https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ on that bare repo? (make a copy first, just for safekeeping)

Comment: @VonC I have during yesterday experimented a lot with BFG (thanx). And I like it a lot, but it is not as fine grained as "git filter-branch" is.

Comment: Sure: the point was just to see if that would help reducing the size (providing you delete the extra folder it creates)

Comment: @VonC I have during yesterday experimented a lot with BFG (thanx). And I like it a lot, but it is not as fine grained as "git filter-branch" is. However a great thing was to run "bfg-1.12.16.jar -B 20" which prints the top list of bloat files. I learned that "Joe Average" commited a core file, several pdf files etc on "personal" work branches. Lovely :) Those I have nuked now with "git filter-branch".

Comment: Status; I am down from 2GB to 450MB using harder git filter-branch + git gc. Similar work with bfg + git gc gives me 1100MB. I clearly have left over SHAs with bloat, that I cannot clean up with with gc after deleting all relevant branches with "bloat" commits.

Comment: Even (in the case of bfg) after a `git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive`?

Comment: git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive -> does not reduce directory size of the bare repo - however cloning from bare to a normal git repo and running this command reduces directory size from 450 MB to 55 MB (all branches + all tags are intact)

Comment: Any filter-branch or bgf would leave behind some extra folder to be removed. (like `refs/original`). Is it possible the size of the bare repo is still big because of those original elements?

Comment: I doubt it - however I tried http://www.ducea.com/2012/02/07/howto-completely-remove-a-file-from-git-history/ and see $ git verify-pack -v objects/pack/*.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail -3  gives 
  2a31e09d92ad07ef7eb4fd4f35f3cdfa6534f26d blob   824965 742807 10737178  
b618d754d3fe6859cc93bd82ee0c62d4bfa734c7 blob   849168 116649 8739945 2   a930f65043cc1e1bbb7e5d5f2fd15d327ff9e37f
97041233c36c3d4c2d3bc133840c35be7a978684 blob   1152730 80523 139905523  
how to use?

Comment: You are supposed to use `git rev-list --objects --all | grep <revision_id>` to find the filenames behind those revisions.

Comment: @PeterToft `git gc --aggressive --prune=yes` should also work for bare repo. Can you show the detail `objects/` size after executing `git gc --aggressive --prune=yes`? And what's the `.git/objects/` size if you execute `git gc --aggressive --prune=yes` in cloned repo?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT See https://pastebin.com/jPTz8XwJ  Very fishy that in the bare repo I cannot reduce the size of huge .git/objects/pack/pack-cf4df31d6c14f939915003a0e4da76a3e19b2b3f.pack  I have git 2.7.4

Comment: Retested with git 2.16.1 -> same results

Comment: @PeterToft Based on the screen shot, all the loose objects has already been packed into `.git/objects/pack/*.pack `. If there has not new changes committed after that, the size of the `.git/objects/` won't be changed even you execute `git gc` again. And based on the git gc document https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc, it also says "git-gc - Cleanup unnecessary files and optimize the **local repository**".

Comment: I start to suspect that the culpit is centered around submodule handling

Comment: @PeterToft do you have any .gitmodules in your repo?

Comment: If the directory size drops to an acceptable level on a cloned repo, what is the problem with coping the `.git` directory from the cloned repo to the original repo?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what is missing to your command:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

also try: ***BFG Repo-Cleaner***

```
https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/
```